# Помогите написать скрипт, не могу додуматься

Tags: android

Имеются 3 кнопки подряд , как лесенка , 1 кнопка ниже 2 и 3 кнопка под 2 , при нажатии на любую кнопку надо что бы под кнопкой выводилось пару картинок в нужном порядке . То есть образно "открыть" кнопку и посмотреть что в ней , так же если "открыть" 2 сразу они оставались открытыми

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить - его суть сводится к вытаскиванию из вас клещами вашей настоящей проблемы и после этого написанию за вас кода. Попробуйте избежать нужды привлекать способности менеджеров и системных аналитиков и оставить вопрос только для прогеров - приведите код и локализируйте проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(view->{
    image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_luancher);
    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE));
}
```